# http post request with scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, oauth-2.0, oauth

I need to make a post request like

```
POST https://oauth2.stv.com/oauth2/token
Body: grant_type=client_credentials; scope=runtime:read application:read label_definition:read
Authorization: Basic <client id>:<client secret>
```

And use the following

```
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'https://oauth2.stv.com/oauth2/token',
            data: qs.stringify({
                grant_type: 'client_credentials',
                scope: 'runtime:read application:read label_definition:read',
            }),
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                Authorization: 'Basic user:pass',
            },

        }),
```

And get this error

'ECONNRESET' http 400

maybe its relate to `scope` as im not sure that I use multi `scope` (didnt see in the docs example how to use multiple scopes) field in the right way, any idea ?